# Importing installed node modules vs importing css or other files in React

Tags: react-native, directory, router

Could someone explain why this:

```
import React from '../node_modules/react';
```

is the same as:

```
import React from 'react';
```

and this:

```
import './App.css';
```

is NOT the same as:

```
import 'App.css';   or import 'App.css';
```

in the later example I get a message that the file App.css can not be found in the src directory but it is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed Node Modules can be imported without specifying the path.

App.css is not a node module and therefore the path needs to be specified

Since the release of [create react app V3](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v3.0.0) you can also type out absolute paths instead of the sometimes confusing method './../file.js'

Comment: but why do you need to specify the current directory with a dot '.'

Comment: thats the default react syntax - unless its a node module which you can import without that piece of syntax

Answer (score 2):

It identifies the modules by name

But files it detects only by path
As you will see in  [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

> module-name
>   The module to import from. This is often a relative or absolute path name to the .js file containing the module. Certain bundlers may permit or require the use of the extension; check your environment. Only single quoted and double quoted Strings are allowed.
>
> name
>   Name of the module object that will be used as a kind of namespace when referring to the imports.

Comment: but why do you need to specify the current directory with a dot '.'

Comment: So he knew you were giving him a path and not a name